# How do I subset a panel data set with three criteria in Stata?

Tags: dataframe, subset, stata, panel-data

I have a panel dataset that looks like this:

| person_id | year | cash |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 2020q4 | 6,000 |
| 222 | 2021q1 | 7,000 |
| 222 | 2021q2 | 8,000 |
| 321 | 2020q4 | 4,000 |
| 321 | 2021q4 | 11,000 |
| 321 | 2021q2 | 15,000 |

I want to subset the data set for the groups of person_id's that have < 10,000 in 2021q2 and keep all of their previous observations as well, and drop the person_ids who don't have that amount of cash by 2021q2. How can I subset this data by the three variables above?

So in this example I want to keep all observations of person_id 222 but drop all observations of 321.

Appreciate any assistance. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/qcswcb/how_do_i_subset_a_panel_data_set_with_three/  It's always polite to mention cross-posting.  At worst, you waste other people's time if they answer a question already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an even more succinct way to do this, but I would split it up in these three steps:

```
clear
input int person_id str6 year int cash
222 "2020q4"  6000
222 "2021q1"  7000
222 "2021q2"  8000
321 "2020q4"  4000
321 "2021q4" 11000
321 "2021q2" 15000
end

*Test if obs has cash>10000 in 2021 q2
gen subset_obs = (cash > 10000 & year == "2021q2")

*By ID, get the max value in subset_obs to copy 1s to all rows for the ID
bysort person_id : egen subset_id = max(subset_obs)

*Keep only IDs with subset_id is 1
keep if subset_id == 1
```

Comment: I think this worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: The wording in the original is a little awkward. OP wants to drop 321 and keep 222, i.e. OP wants to keep those with cash < 10000. But the idea is basically the same. There's a parallel solution at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/qcswcb/how_do_i_subset_a_panel_data_set_with_three/